# Page reloads immediately after form submit using javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I want to show data after inserting in form div and show results of that submitted form on another div on same page without changing page in wordpress? I used javascript function onSubmit it works according to which i want but after submit form div it shows the hidden result div for few seconds and then it reloads immediately and i dont want to reload or refresh the page after show result div?

Form Code Which Is First Div:

```html
<form  style="margin-top: 30px;" class="form-horizontal t-gray" id="ContactForm" method="post"  onsubmit="document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = ''; return true;" action="">
       <div id="first">

      <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Journey Type:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select class="form-control" name="JourneyType">
          <option value="Distance (point A to Point B)">Distance (point A to Point B)</option>
         <option value="Hourly">Hourly</option>
         </select>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Baby Seat Required:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select class="form-control" name="babyseat"><option value="Not Required">Not Required</option><option value="baby seat">Baby Seat</option>
         <option value="booster seat">Booster Seat</option></select>
       </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;">
       <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Journey From:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="Journey_From" id="inputString" onKeyUp="lookup(this.value);" onBlur="fill();" />
       </div>
       <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
        <!-- <img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" /> -->
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;">
       <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Journey To:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select class="form-control" name="Journey_To"><option value="Melbourne Airport">Melbourne Airport</option>
         <option value="Melbourne CBD">Melbourne CBD</option></select>
       </div>
      </div>
 </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" style="background-color:#e6ae48; border-color:#e6ae48; color:#fff;">Get Quote</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     </form>
    </div></div>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>
```

And this is my Second Div Which Shows Data after first div submit but don't stay for long:

```html
<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none" >
      <?php        
// $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "melbou99_melcars") or die("Could not make connection to the Database.");

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","tanxeelc_singh","singh@123", "tanxeelc_melb") or die("Could not make connection to the Database.");

// $db= mysql_select_db("melbou99_melcars",$conn) or die("Could not select the Database.");
//$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not make connection to the Database.");
//$db= mysql_select_db("nz",$conn) or die("Could not select the Database.");
// old pass - !Cmo_;,cBb^A
?>
  <div class="container booking-area">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   <center> <h3 class="">Online Price Calculator:</h3> </center>
                   <center>    <p class="t-gray"> Based on your selection, the price estimation is as follows. This is just the estimation not the final price.</p></center>

       <?php
       
       $journeytype= $_REQUEST['JourneyType'];
       $babyseat= $_REQUEST['babyseat'];
       $journeyfrom= $_REQUEST['Journey_From'];
       $journeyto= $_REQUEST['Journey_To'];

       ?> 

       <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM prices where value='$journeyfrom'"; 
       $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
        $value=$myrow[1];
        $cbd=$myrow[2]; 
        $melb_air=$myrow[3];
        $ava_air=$myrow[4];
       }
       
       ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
     <h4 class="">Journey Type:</h4>
     <p class="t-gray"><?php echo $journeytype; ?></p>

     <h4 class="">Baby Seat Required:</h4>
     <p class="t-gray"><?php echo $babyseat; ?></p>

     <h4 class="">Journey From:</h4>
     <p class="t-gray"><?php echo $journeyfrom; ?></p>

     <h4 class="">Journey To:</h4>
     <p class="t-gray"><?php echo $journeyto; ?></p>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 pull-right" style="padding-right:100px;margin-top:5%;">
<h2 align="center">Fare:<br/>
     <span class="fare_p">
      <?php
        
        if($journeytype=="One Way Journey"){
         
          if($journeyto=="Melbourne Airport"){
           $fare= $melb_air;
          }
          elseif($journeyto=="Avalon Airport"){
            $fare=  $ava_air;
          }
          elseif($journeyto=="Melbourne CBD"){
            $fare=  $cbd;
          }
          if($babyseat=="baby seat"|| $babyseat== "booster seat"){
           $fare=$fare+10;
          }
           else{
            $fare=$fare+0;
          }
         echo "One way fare = $" .$fare ;
        }
        elseif($journeytype=="Return Journey"){
         
         if($journeyto=="Melbourne Airport"){
          $fare= $melb_air;
          
         }
         elseif($journeyto=="Avalon Airport"){
           $fare= $ava_air;
           
         }
         elseif($journeyto=="Melbourne CBD"){
            $fare= $cbd;
            
         }
         $fare=$fare*2;
         if($babyseat=="baby seat"||$babyseat== "booster seat"){
         $fare=$fare+10;
         
         }
         else{
         $fare=$fare+0;
         
        }
         echo "Return Fare = $" .$fare;
        }
        
        ?>
                                </span>
                                <br/><br/>
 
     </h2>

</div>

</div><!--row-->



    
   </div>
 
 
  </div><!--row-->
 </div><!--fluid-->
 </div>
```

Comment: your code is hard to read ... suggest you look up event.preventDefault

Comment: You need to stop the first form Submitting if you don't want the page to reload. However, it looks like you need the form to submit to get the data for the second Div - is that right?

Comment: yes i want first div data to submit and show in second div which is hidden but when i use return false; in java script function it doesn't reload but also don't get data from the first div

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` by passing `e` into your `onsubmit` function.

What this does is, in simple terms, it changes the default behavior of the event. In your case of submitting a form, the page in the browser would not refresh. You can read more about `event.preventDefault()` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Doing inline JavaScript function calling inside HTML elements is not considered best practice, at least not when developing in vanilla JS. Rather, you would use an HTML reference of your element, in this case preferably an `id`, within a seperate JS-file or a `script` tag.

To reference your form you would then do:

ES6 (recommended)

```
const contactForm = document.getElementById('ContactForm');
```

ES5

```
var contactForm = document.getElementById('ContactForm');
```

Binding the submit event could then be done either simply through dot notation:

```
contactForm.onsubmit = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // do some other stuff
};
```

Or by adding an event listener:

```
contactForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // keep doing stuff
}, false);
```

Most JS developers prefer the `addEventListener()` method as it gives them more control over the event handling. However, in your case it could be considered superfluous.

Comment: I have updated my answer in much more detail. Hope it helps!

Comment: Again Same issue both of the code does not work...!!

Comment: Did you remove all your inline function calling from the HTML tag?